# Rendering DB values using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, database-design, normalization

Till date in a project of mine there has been straight forward implementation of DB normalization and the way "status codes" are stored , for example

Patient_table

```
patientId | referralStatus

  1001            1
  1002            2
```

Referral_status_codes_master

```
refStatusCode | refValue
      1         Pending
      2         Awaiting
```

Joining these two tables gives appropriate data for "STATUS_CODES" .
My intent here is , would it be appropriate if i use Javascript to achieve this for relatively small Master table values , i.e which don't change at all , like status here for example .

let's say i load patient data in a HTML table as it is and by using javascript i change their meanings .

```
<tr>
  <td>1001</td>
  <td>1</td>
</tr>
```

**Objective : Intead of using join in sql query , obtain same results using Javascript on client side.**

and i bind that HTML table to a JS function and change status 1 to "Pending", i know it's possible ,my Question is :

1. **What are the disadvantages of doing it .**
2. **Are there any Libraries already existing for this very purpose only.**

Please provide your suggestions .

Thank you

Comment: Its not really clear what tu suggest.. which database? server?

Comment: Well , i'm using Mysql DB , but the question is generic to all DBs , have edited the question .

Answer (score 1):

Since you have finite number of statuses, you can map values to user friendly name and than just replace them using js/jQuery

```js
var statusMap = {
  '1': 'Normal',
  '2': 'Missing',
  '3': 'Dead',
};

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('[data-status]').each(function () {
    $(this).html(statusMap[$(this).data('status')]);
  })
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 50%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John Wick</td>
    <td data-status="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Abraham Lincoln</td>
    <td data-status="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dummy User</td>
    <td data-status="2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

`statusMap` can be generated from PHP side by doing `json_encode({All values from Referral_status_codes_master});`

Comment: Yup , i have done something similar , well what i want to know is , is there any disadvantage in doing this , suppose a year later i want to add a new status , then let's say i change the JS file , i would still work , i want to know is it good practice .

Comment: And need to know if there are any JS libraries for this purpose only .

Comment: @RakeshBk Since you will generate map from existing values, you can get to situation where you have no such status name for old entry (bad back-end architecture). All you do there is you move server action to user action

Comment: I didn't quite understand that , can you please explain what you meant by "No such status name for old entry" , because status names will be there for old and newly added .

Comment: @RakeshBk If you delete status #404 but leave patients with status #404.

Comment: Well , that is true in case of DB as well . isn't it ?